# how to get specific image url from google in java

Tags: java, excel, image, jsoup

I want to get the image address of first result from google and save into excel sheet. I use apache poi library for reading excel sheet.
I want src data as per image. and other thing is that src data in image is not full. We have to double click on it to copy whole data.
I tried jsoup library and but not getting correct result. Please suggest me any change.

[image]

```
package com.uc.excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ReadExcelFileDemo {
   public static void main(String...args) throws IOException {
   final String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL ="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
   //https://www.google.co.in/search?q=usa&hl=en&tbm=isch
   FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\users\\hvt\\desktop\\country.xlsx"));  
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);   
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);     //creating a Sheet object to retrieve object  
   Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();    //iterating over excel file  
   while (itr.hasNext())                 
   {  
       Row row = itr.next();  
       Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();   //iterating over each column  
       while (cellIterator.hasNext())   
       {  
           Cell cell = cellIterator.next();  
           System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
            String searchURL=GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL+cell.getStringCellValue()+" flag"+"&hl=en&tbm=isch"; 
            System.out.print(searchURL);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).get();
            Elements link = doc.select("img.rg_i Q4LuWd");
            
            System.out.println("link2 " +link.attr("src"));
            System.out.println("link2 " +link.toString());
           

       }  
   System.out.println("");  
   }  
}
}
```

Comment: This type of src doesn't contain an image address. It contains the image itself stored as binary data encoded using base64. You can decode it and save to file.

Comment: ok, but what i need is the url of the image. Like When we right click on image, and copy image address.